# How do I get a portion of the title after the indexof a word - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a shortcode generating a list of posts. Each shows the title with `get_the_title()`.

However, I need to indexOf the title to show only a portion of it and remove the constant part. I can't just update the title of the post, although that would be easier because I am using the title as is somewhere else.

Example:

List of post titles:

> Words from a farm in Rochester, NY
>
> Words from a farm in Springfield, OH
>
> Words from a farm in West York, PA
>
> Words from a farm in Homestead, FL

Then in the functions.php file, I have a loop to the title like this

```
$string .= '<h4 class="uk-card-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
```

I need something that removes the "Words from a farm in " only in the loop

CODE

```
    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        $string .= '<div class="uk-container-expand">';
        $string .= '<div class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries posts" uk-grid="masonry: true">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $text = str_replace('Words from a farm in ', '', get_the_title());

            $string .= '<div class="uk-width-1-3@m uk-width-1-1@s">';
                $string .= '<div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-secondary-alt post">';
                    $string .= '<div class="uk-card-header">';                  
                        $string .= '<h4 class="uk-card-title">';
                            $string .= str_replace('Words from a farm in ', '', get_the_title());
                            $string .= $text; 
                        $string .= '</h4>';
                    $string .= '</div>';
                    $string .= '<div class="uk-card-body">';
                        $string .= '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
                    $string .= '</div>';
                $string .= '</div>';
            $string .= '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    return $string;
```

Comment: Have a look at `apply_filters()` + `add_filter()` docs it might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest but least elegant:

```
str_replace('Words from a farm in ', '', get_the_title())
```

Comment: I jumped the gun. It didn't quite work. But it's probably a misplacement. I'm going to edit the question. Can you take a look at the loop?

Comment: It looks like if anything you would be duplicating the City string by concatenating both the str_replace and $text to the string. Does the return string from this function have any text at all in it?

Comment: The duplicate shows two ways of using it. (inline or by a $text storage). I'm intending to use one of them only. But neither does what I need

Comment: OMG, I'm a dufus! Sorry, I was looking for the wrong string. The one I posted in my question was an example, the actual string was written slightly different so it didn't find it. I apologize.

Comment: I hope I was able to help. Using str_replace('Words from a farm in ', '', get_the_title()) should certainly work wherever you were previously using get_the_title(), but obviously it is depending heavily on the underlying title data to adhere to this rigid format.